# How to get the item in the list with largest length

Tags: python

How would I get the longest item in the following list comprehension?

```
lc = [item.decode('utf-8') for l in srt_breakdown.values() for item in l]
```

Here is how I would get it's length:

```
max_length = max([len(item.decode('utf-8')) for l in srt_breakdown.values() for item in l]
```

How would I get the actual text of the max_length item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `key` keyword argument; set it to `len` to find the longest string:

```
max_length = max(
    (item.decode('utf-8') for l in srt_breakdown.values() for item in l),
    key=len)
```

Note that I used a generator expression so as not to build the whole list of strings in memory first; instead strings are decoded as needed.

`max()` will return the first string whose `key(element)` result is highest. By using `len` as the `key` that means that `max()` will find the longest string.